# REGEX a JSON style string using any single character

Tags: php, json, regex, string, validation

The string needing validated is in the following format, which is not strictly JSON and cannot be validated using PHP's JSON encoding process. Note the %%'s in the keys are required.

```
// As a single pair
{"%%key%%":"value"}

// Or comma delimited pairs
{"%%key%%":"value","%%key 2%%":"value 2", ...etc...}
```

The current REGEX successfully validates for the above:

```
\{"%%[a-zA-Z0-9]+%%":"[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"(?:,"%%[a-zA-Z0-9]+%%":"[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+")*}
```

Valid Example: https://regex101.com/r/4y1uEu/1

Invalid Example (no quotes around second value): https://regex101.com/r/4y1uEu/2

---

Values need to support additional characters, ideally any character, so I changed the REGEX to

```
\{"%%[a-zA-Z0-9]+%%":".+"(?:,"%%[a-zA-Z0-9]+%%":".+")*}
```

Which matches for this string which does not match the desired pattern:

```
{"%%hello%%":"world","%%foo%%":bar"}
                              ^ missing quote
```

Example of false positive: https://regex101.com/r/4y1uEu/3

---

I believe reason is that the new "any character" is being used for this ***whole section:***
{"%%hello%%":"***world","%%foo%%":bar***"}

---

How can I somehow make "any character" matching end? Is this method doomed to fail due to a quote itself being "any character"?

---

Some examples of expected results:

`{"%%hello%%":"world","%%foo%%":"bar"}` Valid

`{"%%hello%%":"world lorem","%%foo%%":"bar ipsum"}` Valid

`{"%%hello%%":"world lo-rem","%%foo%%":"bar ips'um"}` Valid

`{"%%hello%%":"world lo-rem","%%foo%%":"lorem "ipsum" dolor"}` Valid

Comment: So this would be pretty easy except for the non-escaped quotes within quotes `"lorem "ipsum" dolor"`.  Why save invalid JSON?

Comment: `\{"%%[a-zA-Z0-9]+%%":"[^"]+"(?:,"%%[a-zA-Z0-9]+%%":"[^"]+")*\}`

Comment: with "everything allowed" in the value part, and quotes left un-escaped, {"%%hello%%":"world","%%foo%%":bar"} is valid with 1 key-value pair as key="%%hello%%" and value = "world","%%foo%%":bar". The easiest way to avoid this is to either not allow ',' or '%' in the value part, or you need to more clearly define why that value is invalid while anything else is.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var pattern = /^{("%%[a-zA-Z0-9]+%%":"([A-z0-9\s\\"'-])*"\s*(,|})\s*)*$/
str = "{\"%%hello%%\":\"world lo-rem\",\"%%foo%%\":\"lorem \"ipsum\" dolor\"}"
console.log(str+ ' '+pattern.test(str))
str = "{\"%%hello%%\":\"world lo-rem\",\"%%foo%%\":\"bar ips'um\"}"
console.log(str+ ' '+pattern.test(str))
str = "{\"%%hello%%\":\"world\",\"%%foo%%\":bar\"}"
console.log(str+ ' '+pattern.test(str))
str = "{\"%%hello%%\":\"world\",\"%%foo%%\":bar}"
console.log(str+ ' '+pattern.test(str))
```

Using your rules for valid keys and extending valid values in the value string, this should work for what you asked.

^{("%%[a-zA-Z0-9]+%%":"([A-z0-9\s\\"'-])*"\s*(,|})\s*)*$

And for JSON escape " version...

^{("%%[a-zA-Z0-9]+%%":"([A-z0-9\s\\'-]|\\")*"\s*(,|})\s*)*$